# Math operations on lengths

Tags: tables, calculations, lengths

I have a table with three columns and I want the table to be distributed on `\textwidth` of the page.

I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth/3}{| c | c | c |} %Math operation here.
\hline
looooooong & long & very loooong \\
long & very looooooong & long\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: use `begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | c | X |}`  for example. Or three times the column specifier `X` if you have three wide colums with linebreaks

Comment: While you're using [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx), it seems like you haven't read the [`tabularx` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf). Please do!

Comment: @Herbert wow it worked, what does X do? I have read this page https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabularx_package

Comment: @Werner just saw your comment thanks, I read that  The X column speciﬁcation will be converted to p{hsome valuei} once the correct column width has been calculated.

Comment: But It interests me to know, can you do math operations on such things in LaTeX? Can you save \textwidth in a variable and then use it later on? Or can I somehow print \textwidth at least to I know the size and then divide it by 3 myself?

Comment: @Shayan: The `X` columns share the remaining space, after the other type columns have been placed, so the prescribed width (here \textwidth) is exactly filled. What you suggest doing by yourself is overly complicated: you'd have to take into account the separations between columns, and the rule widths if you have any vertical lines.

Comment: @Bernard thanks, also, `m` parameter of `tabular` doesn't work with `tabularx` any solution to vertically center the columns?

Comment: You can redefine the `X` column type so that it becomes `m{some length}` instead of `p{some length}` (see p. 3 in the documentation).

Comment: @Bernard The part `Diﬀerences between tabularx and tabular*` ? I don't unserstand anything about it, please kindly elaborate.

Comment: Well, roughly speaking, `tabular*`adds the necessary extra spacing between columns so the table width is what you require, whereas `tabularx` calculates the width of each column. There can be differences in the result, as you can see from the link you mentioned. Also, `tabularx` can break lines within a cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X |} \hline
        \lipsum[5] & \lipsum[5] & \lipsum[5]\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
    | >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X 
    | X 
    | >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X |} \hline
    \lipsum[5] & \lipsum[5] & \lipsum[5]\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

If you need the possibility of a pagebreak then use `xltabular` instead.

Comment: This is what I wanted to distribute text evenly and `lipsum` generates an article? nice, Do I need the first `tabularx` in my code as well or was it just to generate the article? EDIT: Nevermind :D

Comment: No, this doesn't distribute evenly (Share the extra space with other columns)

Comment: The first `tabularx` has three columns with equal width and the second `tabularx` shows how you can get `X` columns with different width.  The `lipsum` package is only for generating dummy text.

Answer (score 2):

The following two approaches provides the same output; the first uses calculations on `\textwidth` to distribute the columns evenly, while the second uses [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx)'s `X`-columns to compute the lengths:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{tabular}
  { | *{3}{p{\dimexpr(\textwidth - \arrayrulewidth)/3 - 2\tabcolsep - \arrayrulewidth} |} }
  \hline
  looooooong & long & very loooong \\
  long & very looooooong & long \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | *{3}{X |} }
  \hline
  looooooong & long & very loooong \\
  long & very looooooong & long \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

`X`-columns default to `p{<len>}` after `<len>` is determined. If you want to change this, you can use

```
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{ m{#1} }
```

to vertically centre the column entries, for example (`m{<len>}` is provided by [`array`](//ctan.org/pkg/array), which is loaded by `tabularx`).

Comment: I have `\usepackage{array}` but \begin tabular `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X m{4.7cm} | X m{4.7cm} | X m{4.7cm} |}` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: (That's how I would go about centering columns vertically with `tabular`

Comment: @Shayan: For centering columns vertically, use `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}` and then `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | X | X | X | }`.

Comment: oh ok, I didn't know what that command was about, I don't know [1]{m{#1} does, also can't yet upvote comments so thanks

Comment: If you see the output of your code which you inluded on your answer, there's blank space on each column, any way to get rid of the blank space to make the table smaller?

Comment: @Shayan: That space is given by `\tabcolsep` - the `sep`eration between each `col`umn in a `tab`ular. You can `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5\tabcolsep}` to reduce it by 50%, or `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}` to fix it to `1pt` (default is `6pt`).

Comment: thanks that command is very useful but I mean something like this https://prnt.sc/htj7sd